# Get all go structs from a file or package

Tags: go, struct

```
import "github.com/alecthomas/jsonschema"
import "internal/structs"
func main(){
    schema := jsonschema.Reflect(&structs.Struct1{})
...
}
```

I have a requirement to access all structures under this package and iterate over them. How can I do this?

Comment: Manually list a value for each type in the package.  To automate, write a program to be invoked by the [go generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) command.  This program loads the package AST using [x/packages.Load](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#Load),  [walks](https://godoc.org/go/ast#Walk) through the AST looking for struct type declarations and writes a Go file containing a slice literal of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Go's built-in `ast` package.
Here is an example of what you need: https://gist.github.com/LukaGiorgadze/570a89a5c3c6d006120da8c29f6684ee